# Send message with cloud api whatsapp and google app script

Tags: api, google-apps-script, whatsapp

Meta recently released the cloud api to send messages from Whatsapp business, but I can't send it from the google app script.

I have this code, it runs fine... but it doesn't reach the user

```
    function SendToUser() {
      var headers = {
        'Authorization' : 'Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        };
         
        var payload = {
        "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
        "recipient_type": "individual",
        "to": "PHONE_NUMBER",
        "type": "text",
        "text": { // the text object
           "preview_url": false,
           "body": "MESSAGE_CONTENT"
        }
       }
       
      var options = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: headers,
        payload: JSON.stringify(payload) // <--- Modified
      }
    
      let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/FROM_PHONE_NUMBER_ID/messages", options);

      Logger.log(response)
            
    }
```

Comment: I think the content type should be part of the headers. Also, the code might run but what is the response you are getting back?

Comment: {"messaging_product":"whatsapp","contacts":[{"input":"PHONE_NUMBER","wa_id":"PHONE_NUMBER"}],"messages":[{"id":"wamid.HBgNNTQ5MzU0MTU2MjE4MhUCABEYEjBEMUM1NjU0M0ZBMjAzNEMyOQA="}]}

Comment: I already changed the content-type to the header, and that is the response I get

Comment: Then it seems to be working, the issue here would be with facebook.

Comment: Maybe you skipped this: confirm your phonenumber for whatsapp api

Comment: I think the user needs to save your contact first

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happens to me, the answer is correct but the message does not arrive, only the example of the Hellow_Word template is working, the others are not.

Answer (score 1):

See this project...

https://github.com/pro-cms/whatsappcloud-php

This work for me :)

Comment: Its google app script

Answer (score 0):

Have look at [Heyooh](https://github.com/JS-Hub-ZW/heyooh), it's a Javascript Wrapper for WhatsApp Cloud API

**Installation**

```bash
npm install heyooh
```

Here how sending to send messages;

```py
import WhatsApp from heyhooh
let messenger = new WhatsApp('TOKEN',  phone_number_id='104xxxxxx')
messenger.send_template("hello_world", "255757xxxxxx")
```

Comment: Its google app script

Answer (score 0):

dear friends of the stackoverflow community, The official documentation indicates that in order to send such messages, **the conversation must be initiated by the user**. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/conversation-types

[image]

Comment: Kudos man this is the correct answer.  Spam prevention!

Comment: This is an incorrect answer, the documentation indicate you need a pre-approved template by the meta developer team.

Answer (score 0):

only approved templates can be sent as first message from whatsapp API account/phone number, try sending any message say 'Hi' back to api whatsapp account/phone number by the recipient to whom you were sending the message in the above script and then run the script, it runs for me by doing this.

---